# Suggestion required for MQ Virtualization with KarateDSL

Tags: karate

We are in process of virtualizing/mocking MQ's. Our Team is evaluating Karate DSL for the same. We have gone [Tweet-JavaInterOp - JMS/MQ Virtualization](https://twitter.com/getkarate/status/1417023536082812935) this link. We have below questions for which any help from Karate Team will be helpful.

1. For MQ Virtualization/mocking - Do we need tech stack knowledge of SpringBoot or other technology other than JAVA?
2. Any pre-requisite involved in running KarateDSL for MQ Virtualization/mocking?
3. Any Sample project where we can take reference for MQ connectivity with help of KarateDSL?

**Our Virtualization/Mocking Use Case:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

1. No. You just write the bare minimum Java code that can replace the piece that you are mocking. I can't provide more of an answer unless I see example code.
2. No. Just Java, just like any Maven or Gradle project
3. Yes: https://twitter.com/getkarate/status/1128170638223364097